# How do I check the state of a checkbox for macOS applications using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, checkbox, nsbutton

The task seemed relatively simple, I wanted an if statement to determine if a check box is checked or not apparently check boxes but am at a loss

I've tried

if checkbox.state == everythign i can think of but it always errors either EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION or using wrong cant convert variable type to other variable type

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Xcode 9 • Swift 4**

You can switch the checkbox state property to check if it is on or off as follow:

```
switch sender.state {
case .on:
    print("on")
case .off:
    print("off")
case .mixed:
    print("mixed")
default: break
}
```

Comment: you should use the enumerated constants NSOnState and NSOffState

Comment: Just a side note: the else part covers NSOffState and NSMixedState.

Answer (score 4):

i did this on my project and it worked well

```
if sender.state == .on{
            casa_ospiti_text.stringValue = "CASA"
        }
        else{
            casa_ospiti_text.stringValue = "OSPITI"
        }
```

where it changes the value of a textfield (casa_ospiti_text) with constants strings.